# TikZ - Is it possible to draw a line over the whole page

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create/draw a front page of a document and therefore I want to draw a line from one corner of the Page to another. Ok in the final version I want to implement some control points. But up until now I can´t get the drawing to work when I use "page coordinates" instead of points...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}    

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \coordinate (A) at (current page.north east, current page.north east);
    \coordinate (B) at (current page.north, current page.south);
    \draw[line width=1.5pt]%, cap=round]
    (A) -- (B)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! You are missing a final semicolon after the `(A) -- (B)`.

Comment: Also `(current page.north east, current page.north east)` does not make sense, It is sort of like `((a,b),(c,d)` `(current page.north east)` **is** a coordinate on the page

Comment: Note that if you want to print this you should enlarge the page by about 3mm to prevent problems with the tolerance at cutting the pages … see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_(printing)

Answer (score 8):

This works just fine. You had the coordinates wrong and a missing `;`. I've removed a few packages that are not relevant for the mwe

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\begin{document}
 \thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \coordinate (A) at (current page.north west);
    \coordinate (B) at (current page.south east);
    \draw[red, very thick]%, cap=round]
    (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

Test


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It isn't entirely clear which line you are trying to draw: a line from the left to right of the page? a diagonal? (which one?)

This example uses colours to distinguish four possibilities:

[image: 4 lines]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \coordinate (A) at (current page.north west);
    \coordinate (B) at (current page.south east);
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, cap=round, red]
    (A) -- (B);
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, cap=round, blue]
    ([yshift=-15pt]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-15pt]current page.north east);
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, cap=round, green]
    ([yshift=15pt]current page.south west) -- ([yshift=15pt]current page.south east);
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, cap=round, magenta]
    (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The errors were likely caused by the two problems identified in comments:

1. The final `\draw` command must end in a terminating semicolon.
2. `(current page.north,current page.north)` is not a location. It confuses the `(<x>,<y>)` syntax with the `(<named coordinate>)` syntax. If you need something like this, you can say `(<named coordinate 1> -| <named coordinate 2>)` which will use the `x` bit of `<named coordinate 1>` and the `y` bit of `<named coordinate 2>`. In the case of the `current page` coordinates there isn't much point because the relevant points are all defined anyway.

However, for purposes of demonstration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
     \draw[line width=1.5pt]
    (current page.south west) .. controls (10,-10) .. (current page.north -| current page.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: curved]