# zref: Unstable output when conditionally appending a tikz-drawn page using \ztotpages with \AtVeryEndDocument

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, draft, zref

I need to append a draft page only if the total number of pages in the main document is odd.

The following works well

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{blindtext,tikz,ulem,atveryend,hyperref}
\usepackage[totpages,user]{zref}
\newcommand\DraftPage{%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263613/2288
    \clearpage
    \begingroup
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at ([yshift=-2cm]current page.north) {\LARGE\textbf{\uline{Draft Page}}};
    \draw[line width=5pt]
    (current page.north west) -- (current page.south east);
    \draw[line width=5pt]
    (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}%
    \clearpage
    \endgroup
}
\AtVeryEndDocument{
    \ifodd\ztotpages 
    \DraftPage
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
    \blindtext[1-30]\\
    \textbf{Total number of pages is \ztotpages.}
    \DraftPage
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

until changing it to

```
\begin{document}
    \blindtext[1-30]\\
    \textbf{Total number of pages is \ztotpages.}
\end{document}
```

then I get on the second page a wrongly rendered appended draft page.

[image]

[image]

So, I have two questions:

1- How to make the command `\DraftPage` not affect the total number of pages detected by `\ztotpages` in the former working case? In other words. `\ztotpages` needs to be `1`.

2- Why does the second case result in the wrong output? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

An another solution, hopefully this time more stable:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz,ulem,etoolbox,hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[totpages,user]{zref}
\newcommand\DraftPage{
    \cleardoublepage                % <---
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \ifodd\thepage\else             % <---
    \centering\LARGE\textbf{\uline{Draft Page}} % <--- 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[line width=5pt]
    (current page.north west) -- (current page.south east);
    \draw[line width=5pt]
    (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
   \fi%                             % <---
}
\AtEndDocument{\DraftPage}          % <---

\begin{document}
    \lipsum%\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \textbf{Number of pages is \ztotpages.}
\end{document}
```

This solution in documents with odd number of pages add `\DraftPage` on the end of document.  This is obtained after at least two compilation of documents. I tested the solution with documents with up to five pages of text. All results was correct after two compilations.

- Definition of the `\DraftPage` is changed. Now it contain the test if the last page is odd.
- In my MWE I use `lipsum` instead `blindtext` since I'm more familiar with it.
- In solution is used the `etoolbox` package and its document hook `\AtEndDocument` instead of `atveryend` package and its hook `\AtVeryEndDocument`, which to my best knowledge doesn't work as you expected (but I may be wrong).
- In solution is not used `\ztotpages` anymore. It now serve only for show the number of documents' page.

Comment: May I know why you added `\mbox{}`?

Comment: It actually start `\DraftPag` page. Without it you obtain only part of image as you shown in your question.

Comment: Please try this one: `\AtEndDocument{
    \ifodd\ztotpages
    \else 
\DraftPage
    \fi}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    %\lipsum[1-3]
    \textbf{Number of pages is \ztotpages.}
\end{document}`. You will always get different output each time you compile. I only need to print a draft page only if the total number of pages is odd. I think it is a different question needed to be asked separately.

Comment: Do you compile twice? I obtain correct result.

Comment: I compiled a lot of times. Each compile gets different output than the previous run.

Comment: The second compilation is needed due to `tikzpicture` which use options  `remember picture,overlay`. After second compilation result is stable -- always the same. I use recent MikTeX with recent packages, if this matter.

Comment: [This document](https://pastebin.com/viHXQFWD) switches between two pages document and three pages with a wrongly rendered draft page every single run.

Comment: @Diaa, indeed. I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `\BeforeLastShipout`.

```latex
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz,ulem,atveryend,hyperref}
\usepackage[totpages,user]{zref}

\BeforeClearDocument{\clearpage\DraftPage}
\newcommand{\DraftPage}{%
  \ifodd\value{page}\else
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \mbox{}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at ([yshift=-2cm]current page.north) {\LARGE\textbf{\uline{Draft Page}}};
    \draw[line width=5pt]
    (current page.north west) -- (current page.south east);
    \draw[line width=5pt]
    (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}%
    \renewcommand{\DraftPage}{}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-25]

\textbf{Total number of pages is \zpageref{LastPage}.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change into `\lipsum[1-30]`, the additional page is not shipped out.

Comment: Many thanks for this stable solution. If you don't mind I would be happy to make sure I understand some stuff correctly: (1) does `\ifodd\value{page}\else` check the total number of pages is even so that it activates the command `\DraftPage`? It seems superficially to check for even number although I found it activates `\DraftPage` when the total number of pages is odd. (2) why does `\BeforeClearDocument{\clearpage\DraftPage\clearpage\DraftPage}` not work in case I want to append multiple instances of the daft page?

Comment: @Diaa It's necessary to redefine `\DraftPage` to do nothing, otherwise it would add *two* pages. You wanted one, didn't you?

Comment: Kindly, check my previous comment after editing it. I don't quite understand how `\ifodd\value{page}\else` works/means.

Comment: @Diaa I emit `\clearpage` so everything is (hopefully) shipped out. This operation steps the page counter. There are two cases: `page` is even means that the last shipped page was odd and you need `\DraftPage`; otherwise `page` is odd and the last shipped page was even.

Comment: I apologize for not having the enough knowledge to let me fully grasp your technical description. For your previous question of whether or not I need one page, my main target is to check the total number of pages, and it will fall in two cases: (1) `odd number of pages` print a draft page then use `\includepdf{GraphPaper.pdf}` then draft page then `\includepdf{GraphPaper.pdf}`. (2) `even number of pages` print a graph paper with `\includepdf{GraphPaper.pdf}` then draft page then `\includepdf{GraphPaper.pdf}`. So, I started my experimentation by trying to conditionally print the draft page.

Comment: I found out that `\AtEndDocument{
 \ifodd\thepage\else
 \DraftPage
 \fi
 \includepdf{GraphPaper}
 \DraftPage
 \includepdf{GraphPaper}
}` does the job pretty well. I just found that `\AtEndDocument` behaves differently from `\AtVeryEndDocument`, which I don't know if it is worth asking a new question or not.